# Entity Framework, Dynamic Data and Versioning

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-data

I'm in the process of looking around at options for a back office tool.  On the face of it the tool is simple CRUD so I was immediately attracted to Dynamic Data on top of Entity Framework (we're definitely a Microsoft shop!).

The problem is that future requirement is to support versioning.  By this I mean :

1. User performs a series of updates to a series of entities
2. When they are happy they submit the changes
3. Changes persisted to the DB along with enough info to support a rollback

Elsewhere we've got handcrafted app that :

- Includes a version id that is incremented as each new row inserted - i.e. we don't update we add a new row
- A work item table ties together the changes using the version id along with the entity type (table)

So, the question is, how would I achieve a similar end result using entity framework and dynamic data?

If entity framework, etc isn't appropriate - what would you use (.Net)?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to move the logic for the versioning to database triggers. This way you are able to use a standard Dynamic data on top of Entity Framework, and retrofit versioning by running a set of database scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention that in the new Dyanmic Data Preview 3 there is a new feature DomainService which supports Roles based security please see David Ebbo's Serssion from MIX09 here [Microsoft ASP.NET 4.0 Data Access: Patterns for Success with Web Forms MIX09-T47F](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T47F)